# Self paced listening task, unequal number of segments

Tags: python, psychopy

I am trying to set up a self paced listening task that will consist of two kinds of sentences, one with 9 segments and one with 10 (e.g. I /want/to/go/to/the/theater/with/my/friends against I/want/to/go/to/theater/with/my/friends.

I do not know how to do it in a way that the critical segment is skipped for the sentences with nine parts but is available for the sentences with 10 parts.

In addition to this and probably similar, I want to give to my participants comprehension questions for some of the sentences, not all. Is it possible to do it ?

Any kind of advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that takes some sentences and play them word by word, asking a question at regular intervals. It assumes that there are wave sound files named as the words in the same folder as the script, e.g. `I.wav`, `want.wav` etc. It can also take other sound formats, if you just replace `'.wav'` with the desired sound format.

```
full = 'I/want/to/go/to/the/theater/with/my/friends'
partial = 'I/want/to/go/to/theater/with/my/friends'
question_frequency = 5  # How often to ask questions
ISI = 0.5  # Inter-word-interval

import random
from psychopy import visual, sound, event, core
win = visual.Window()
word_sound = sound.Sound()
instruction = visual.TextStim(win)

trials = [{
    'sentence': random.choice((full, partial)),
    'ask_comprehension': int(i % question_frequency == 0), 
    'comprehension_answer': ''} for i in range(10)]

print trials

for trial in trials:
    for word in trial['sentence'].split('/'):
        #word_sound.setSound(word + '.wav')
        word_sound.play()
        core.wait(ISI)

    if trial['ask_comprehension']:
        instruction.text = 'Did you understand this sentence?'
        instruction.draw()
        win.flip()
        trial['comprehension_answer'] = event.waitKeys()[0]
        win.flip()  # Blank screen
```

When finished, you can save `trials` to a csv file.